# load multuple dummy data dinago

Tags: django, windows, command

I have this script

```
python manage.py loaddata ./project_apps/*/fixtures/test/*.json
```

It works perfectly on linux. This scrip says 'take all dirs from /project_apps, in every dirs, if there is fixtures folder take it and than search for /test dir, if there is take it and grab all files there which have .json extension'.

That is fine, but when i run the same command on windows

```
python manage.py loaddata .\project_apps\*\fixtures\test\*.json
```

it throws me an error:

```
there is no fixtures with that '*' name
```

If i pass the absolute path to the file which a want. It is ok. The windows finds it.

So is there an analogous command for windows, to can grab all files i want at once.

Comment: What is *"dinago for windows"* anyway?

Comment: Good point it's nothing